# Firestore type mismatch : The return type 'Stream<List<Flight>>' isn't a 'List<Flight>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In a flutter project, I am trying to return a list of objects as stream from a method. Here is my code:

```
Stream<List<Flight>> getLove(String seamanId) async* {
    yield* _firestore
        .collectionGroup(ConstStrings.seamans)
        .where(ConstStrings.uid, isEqualTo: seamanId)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots()
        .map((querySnapshot) {
      final docref = querySnapshot.docs[0].reference;
      return docref.collection(ConstStrings.flights).snapshots().map(
            (snapshot) => (snapshot.docs
                .map((doc) => FlightDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
                .toList()),
          );
    });
  }
```

But getting the following compilation error :

> The return type 'Stream<List<Flight>>' isn't a 'List<Flight>'

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call the `snapshots()` method, it returns a stream of updates from the database. Since you're calling `snapshots()` nested again in your code, you're essentially returning a `Stream<Stream<List<Flight>>>`.

To prevent this, you need to return a single event/snapshot from the inner read, either by taking a specific event from the stream (e.g. by [calling `first`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-async/Stream/first.html)) or by using `get()` instead of `snapshots()` there.

Comment: Would you please rewrite the method as answer?